# CloudFormation stack Error - Error occurred while GetObject. S3 Error Code: NoSuchKey

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a stack on AWS using CloudFormation.  The following my cloud Formation script.

I have create the S3 bucket in `us-west (Oregon)` region. I have been running the cloudformation script in the same region.

During the creation process, I get the following error. Could you please help me how can I address this error?

CloudFormation Script

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Description: The CloudFormation template for AWS resources required by amazon rekognition video analyzer. 

Parameters:

  SourceS3BucketParameter: 
    Type: String
    MinLength: "1"
    Description: "Enter the name of the S3 bucket containing source .zip files."

  ImageProcessorSourceS3KeyParameter:
    Type: String
    MinLength: "1"
    Description: "Enter the name of the S3 key of Image Processor lambda function .zip file."

  FrameFetcherSourceS3KeyParameter:
    Type: String
    MinLength: "1"
    Description: "Enter the name of the S3 key of Frame Fetcher lambda function .zip file."

  FrameFetcherLambdaFunctionName:
    Type: String
    Default: "framefetcher"
    Description: "Name of the Lambda function that fetches frame metadata from DynamoDB."

  ImageProcessorLambdaFunctionName:
    Type: String
    Default: "imageprocessor"
    Description: "Name of the Lambda function that receives and processes frame images."

  FrameFetcherApiResourcePathPart:
    Type: String
    Default: "enrichedframe"
    Description: "Path part for the API Gateway resource to access FrameFetcher lambda function."

  KinesisStreamNameParameter:
    Type: String
    Default: "FrameStream"
    Description: "Name of the Kinesis stream to receive frames from video capture client."

  FrameS3BucketNameParameter:
    Type: String
    MinLength: "1"
    Description: "Name of the S3 bucket for storage of captured frames."

  DDBTableNameParameter: 
    Type: String
    Default: "EnrichedFrame"
    Description: "Name of the DynamoDB table for persistence & querying of captured frames metadata."

  DDBGlobalSecondaryIndexNameParameter:
    Type: String
    Default: "processed_year_month-processed_timestamp-index"
    Description: "Name of the DDB Global Secondary Index for querying of captured frames by Web UI."

  ApiGatewayRestApiNameParameter:
    Type: String
    Default: "RtRekogRestApi"
    Description: "Name of the API Gateway Rest API."

  ApiGatewayStageNameParameter:
    Type: String
    Default: "development"
    Description: "Name of the API Gateway stage."

  ApiGatewayUsagePlanNameParameter:
    Type: String
    Default: "development-plan"
    Description: "Name of the API Gateway Usage Plan."

Resources:

  FrameS3Bucket:
    Type: "AWS::S3::Bucket"
    Properties: 
      BucketName: !Ref FrameS3BucketNameParameter

  ImageProcessorLambdaExecutionRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties: 
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
            - lambda.amazonaws.com
          Action:
          - sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonKinesisReadOnlyAccess
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonRekognitionReadOnlyAccess
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSNSFullAccess
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchLogsFullAccess
      Path: "/"
    DependsOn:
      - FrameS3Bucket
      - EnrichedFrameTable

  FrameFetcherLambdaExecutionRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties: 
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
            - lambda.amazonaws.com
          Action:
          - sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchLogsFullAccess
      Path: "/"
    DependsOn:
    - FrameS3Bucket
    - EnrichedFrameTable

  FrameStream:
    Type: "AWS::Kinesis::Stream"
    Properties: 
      Name: !Ref KinesisStreamNameParameter
      ShardCount: 1

  ImageProcessorLambda:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: "imageprocessor"
      Description: "Function processes frame images fetched from a Kinesis stream."
      Handler: "imageprocessor.handler"
      Role: !GetAtt ImageProcessorLambdaExecutionRole.Arn
      Code:
        S3Bucket: !Ref SourceS3BucketParameter
        S3Key: !Ref ImageProcessorSourceS3KeyParameter
      Timeout: 40 #seconds
      MemorySize: 128 #MB
      Runtime: python2.7
    DependsOn: 
      - FrameStream
      - ImageProcessorLambdaExecutionRole

  EventSourceMapping:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping"
    Properties: 
      EventSourceArn: !GetAtt FrameStream.Arn
      FunctionName: !GetAtt ImageProcessorLambda.Arn
      StartingPosition: "TRIM_HORIZON"
    DependsOn:
      - FrameStream
      - ImageProcessorLambda

  FrameFetcherLambda:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: "framefetcher"
      Description: "Function responds to a GET request by returning a list of frames up to a certain fetch horizon."
      Handler: "framefetcher.handler"
      Role: !GetAtt FrameFetcherLambdaExecutionRole.Arn
      Code:
        S3Bucket: !Ref SourceS3BucketParameter
        S3Key: !Ref FrameFetcherSourceS3KeyParameter
      Timeout: 10 #seconds
      MemorySize: 128 #MB
      Runtime: python2.7
    DependsOn:
      - FrameFetcherLambdaExecutionRole

  EnrichedFrameTable:
    Type: "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
    Properties:
      TableName: !Ref DDBTableNameParameter
      KeySchema:
        - KeyType: "HASH"
          AttributeName: "frame_id"
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: "frame_id"
          AttributeType: "S"
        - AttributeName: "processed_timestamp"
          AttributeType: "N"
        - AttributeName: "processed_year_month"
          AttributeType: "S"
      ProvisionedThroughput:
            WriteCapacityUnits: 10
            ReadCapacityUnits: 10
      GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
        - IndexName: !Ref DDBGlobalSecondaryIndexNameParameter
          Projection:
            ProjectionType: "ALL"
          ProvisionedThroughput:
            WriteCapacityUnits: 10
            ReadCapacityUnits: 10
          KeySchema:
          - KeyType: "HASH"
            AttributeName: "processed_year_month"
          - KeyType: "RANGE"
            AttributeName: "processed_timestamp"

  # API Gateway Resources
  VidAnalyzerRestApi: 
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi"
    Properties:
      Description: "The amazon rekognition video analyzer public API."
      Name: !Ref ApiGatewayRestApiNameParameter
    DependsOn: FrameFetcherLambda

  EnrichedFrameResource: 
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Resource"
    Properties: 
      RestApiId: !Ref VidAnalyzerRestApi
      ParentId: !GetAtt VidAnalyzerRestApi.RootResourceId
      PathPart: !Ref FrameFetcherApiResourcePathPart

  EnrichedFrameResourceGET:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref VidAnalyzerRestApi
      ResourceId: !Ref EnrichedFrameResource
      ApiKeyRequired: true
      HttpMethod: GET      
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      Integration:
        Type: AWS_PROXY
        IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
        Uri: !Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${FrameFetcherLambda.Arn}/invocations
      MethodResponses:
        - ResponseModels:
            application/json: Empty
          StatusCode: 200
          ResponseParameters:
            "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": true
            "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods": true
            "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers": true

  # Mock integration to allow Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) 
  # for Web UI to invoke API Gateway
  EnrichedFrameResourceOPTIONS:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref VidAnalyzerRestApi
      ResourceId: !Ref EnrichedFrameResource
      ApiKeyRequired: false
      HttpMethod: OPTIONS
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      Integration:
        Type: MOCK
        IntegrationHttpMethod: OPTIONS
        PassthroughBehavior: WHEN_NO_MATCH
        RequestTemplates:
          "application/json": '{"statusCode": 200 }'
        IntegrationResponses: 
          - StatusCode: 200
            ResponseParameters:
              "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'*'"
              "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "'GET,OPTIONS'"
              "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
            ResponseTemplates:
              "application/json": ''
      MethodResponses:
        - ResponseModels:
            application/json: Empty
          StatusCode: 200
          ResponseParameters:
            "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": true
            "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods": true
            "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers": true

  VidAnalyzerApiDeployment:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment"
    Properties:
      Description: "Public API endpoint of video analyzer."
      RestApiId: !Ref VidAnalyzerRestApi
    DependsOn:
      - EnrichedFrameResourceGET
      - EnrichedFrameResourceOPTIONS

  DevStage:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Stage"
    Properties:
      DeploymentId: !Ref VidAnalyzerApiDeployment
      Description: "API development stage of video analyzer."
      RestApiId: !Ref VidAnalyzerRestApi
      StageName: !Ref ApiGatewayStageNameParameter

  DevUsagePlan:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::UsagePlan
    Properties:
      ApiStages:
      - ApiId: !Ref VidAnalyzerRestApi
        Stage: !Ref DevStage
      Description: Development usage plan
      UsagePlanName: !Ref ApiGatewayUsagePlanNameParameter
    DeletionPolicy: Retain #Had to be added to avoid stack deletion failing due to association with DevStage.

  VidAnalyzerApiKey: 
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::ApiKey"
    Properties: 
      Name: "DevApiKey"
      Description: "Video Analyzer Dev API Key"
      Enabled: true
      StageKeys:
        - RestApiId: !Ref VidAnalyzerRestApi
          StageName: !Ref ApiGatewayStageNameParameter
    DependsOn: 
      - VidAnalyzerApiDeployment
      - DevStage

  DevUsagePlanKey:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::UsagePlanKey"
    Properties : 
      KeyId: !Ref VidAnalyzerApiKey
      KeyType: API_KEY
      UsagePlanId: !Ref DevUsagePlan

  #Give API Gateway permission to invoke FrameFetcher lambda function.
  LambdaInvokePermissionSTAR: 
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Permission"
    Properties: 
      FunctionName: !GetAtt FrameFetcherLambda.Arn
      Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
      Principal: "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      SourceArn: !Join [ "", ["arn:aws:execute-api:", !Ref "AWS::Region", ':', !Ref "AWS::AccountId", ':', !Ref VidAnalyzerRestApi, '/*/*/', !Ref FrameFetcherLambdaFunctionName]]
    DependsOn:
      - VidAnalyzerApiDeployment

  LambdaInvokePermissionGET: 
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Permission"
    Properties: 
      FunctionName: !GetAtt FrameFetcherLambda.Arn
      Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
      Principal: "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      SourceArn: !Join [ "", ["arn:aws:execute-api:", !Ref "AWS::Region", ':', !Ref "AWS::AccountId", ':', !Ref VidAnalyzerRestApi, '/*/GET/', !Ref FrameFetcherApiResourcePathPart]]
    DependsOn:
      - VidAnalyzerApiDeployment


Outputs:
  #API Gateway endpoint Id
  VidAnalyzerApiEndpoint:
    Description: "Endpoint for invoking video analyzer API."
    Value: !Ref VidAnalyzerApiDeployment

  #API Key Id
  VidAnalyzerApiKey:
    Description: "Key for invoking video analyzer API."
    Value: !Ref VidAnalyzerApiKey
```

Error:

[image]

The following are the parameters, I have set during the cloudFormation process.

```
Stack name: streamframerekognition
ApiGatewayRestApiNameParameter : RtRekogRestApi
ApiGatewayStageNameParameter : development
ApiGatewayUsagePlanNameParameter : development-plan
DDBGlobalSecondaryIndexNameParameter : processed_year_month-processed_timestamp-index
DDBTableNameParameter : EnrichedFrame
FrameFetcherApiResourcePathPart : enrichedframe
FrameFetcherLambdaFunctionName : framefetcher


ImageProcessorLambdaFunctionName: imageprocessor
ImageProcessorSourceS3KeyParameter : imagestreamframerekognition
KinesisStreamNameParameter : FrameStream


SourceS3BucketParameter : sourcesstreamframerekognition
FrameFetcherSourceS3KeyParameter : ffstreamframerekognition
FrameS3BucketNameParameter : framesbnpstreamframerekognition
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the object key you are providing as `ImageProcessorSourceS3KeyParameter` is not a valid key name, or does not exist. Check that a file with that name exists in your S3 bucket.

Comment: Thanks for the response, @Icehorn ! How can I set the key? I have provided more information for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

In the S3 bucket "sourcesstreamframerekognition" you need to have a zip file with your code (S3 Key) for FrameFetcherSourceS3KeyParameter and ImageProcessorSourceS3KeyParameter.